# Php Soap Request with sending a cookie - I couldn't send cookie

Tags: php, web-services, cookies, curl

Intro: I am trying to implement some files by using a webservice. This webservice let me to call basic methods freely but when it comes to serious ones it needs for a cookie and my session will be establish with that cookie.

My problem: I tried with two ways first i created ordinary cookie by setcookie() function and then created a file like cookie. The second one worked and now my connection creates a cookie file by itself. now i have to send the same cookie file for the complicated/serious function.

but it doesn't work.

If my problem is not clear please ask specificly and pls pls help me someone.

That one is creating cookie file succefully.

```
$soap_do = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/mypath/testFile3.txt");
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 8);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
```

below you will see the code that i tried to send cookie file via curl and this part is not working.

```
$soap_do2 = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/mypath/testFile3.txt");
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header2);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 8);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request2);
$result2 = curl_exec($soap_do2);
```

As you se it is the same code o_O because i don't know what to do so again pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to store your cookie and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` (or `CURLOPT_COOKIE`) to send the cookie.

So soap_do2 needs `curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/mypath/testFile3.txt");`

Maybe your `$soap_request2` is empty or incorrect.

When i do a GetContactInfo() call to this service without any parameter i got the same error. When is send an empty or nonsense parameter like `new SoapParam(new stdClass(), "test")` i got the right response.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got the idea that which one stores and which one sends. That's clear now but i tried and it didnt work what may the problem do you need anything to know about error or sth else...

Comment: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/faulturn:uuid:bb31a2fb-0410-40ee-929b-b313242ad7f4urn:uuid:e571edaf-c0df-4526-ba9c-ad1e97079506http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous2013-04-22T20:42:55Z2013-04-22T20:47:55Zsoap:ServerSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: this seems an erorr of the webservice. Does this service has a wsdl you can show?

Comment: https://www.prontotour.com/PSSaleWsDemo/ProntoSystem.asmx?wsdl

this is the wsdl but I know the company, asked many times for lots of things and they even don't have any well designed documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.

as @Bass Jobsen said We can store cookie with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and send cookie with CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE. That was the one problem. As he told I changed my code and it works now.

my second mistake: I was creating the cookie file everytime at the begining of the code. Now I removed that part.

working code:

```
$soap_do = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/home/mypath/testFile3.txt");
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 8);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
```

above, I told the webservice which file (with exact path) store cookie values.

```
$soap_do2 = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header2);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/home/mypath/testFile3.txt");
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 8);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($soap_do2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request2);
$result2 = curl_exec($soap_do2);
```

above, I send the cookie file with CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE

hope that helps other ones.